# Unexpected modes of a quantum particle in a 2D box

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I have a simple 2D Hamiltonian $H = \frac{k^2}{2m}$ and a square well. I assume $m = \frac{1}{2}$ so the Hamiltonian simplifies to $$H = k^2 = -\nabla^2$$When I solve the Schroedinger equation $H\psi = E\psi$, I would have thought the modes/eigenvectors would be $$\psi(x,y)\propto \sin(\frac{n_x\pi}{L}x)\sin(\frac{n_y\pi}{L_y}y)$$ (see equation 21 [here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Quantum_Mechanics/05.5%3A_Particle_in_Boxes/Particle_in_a_2-Dimensional_Box)) When I solve numerically using a finite-difference scheme, some modes look like that, but others don't. E.g. This is the 6th mode

[image]

Below is the python script that plots the first 10 modes. My question: Is the analytic expression I gave above incorrect? What is the nature of these peculiar modes, and do they have an analytic expression?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 50 # Number of grid points in both directions
L = 1.0 # Square box side length
h = L / (n - 1) # Grid spacing

# Build 2D hamiltonian
lblock = -np.eye(n) / (h * h)
dblock = np.eye(n) * 4.0 / (h * h) - np.eye(n, k=-1) / (h * h)
hamiltonian = np.kron(np.eye(n), dblock) + np.kron(np.eye(n, k=-1), lblock)

# Get eigenvalues and eigenvectors
eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eigh(hamiltonian)

# Plot first 10 modes
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, L, n), np.linspace(0, L, n))
for i in range(10):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
    ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, eigenvectors[:, i].reshape(n, n), linewidth=0.5)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Your link seems to not work

Comment: Hmm, it works for me. Does this link also not work for you? [link](https://batch.libretexts.org/print/url=https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Quantum_Mechanics/05.5%3A_Particle_in_Boxes/Particle_in_a_2-Dimensional_Box.pdf)

Comment: What about degeneracies? As it seems, you have diagonalized the Hamiltonian (numerically)?! Have you tested, numerically, that the functions you give are indeed eigenfunctions? Have you increased the dimension of the space?

Comment: Where are you specifying your boundary conditions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The plotted function looks like $\psi_{(n_x=3,\, n_y=1)} + \psi_{(n_x=1,\, n_y=3)}$ . ([See here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+sin%281*pi*x%29*sin%283*pi*y%29+%2B+sin%283*pi*x%29*sin%28pi*y%29%2C+x%3D0+to+1%2C+y%3D0+to+1)).
This is a valid eigenfunction, since it is a linear combination of eigenfunctions that have the same energy.
When there are degenerate states like this, a numerical eigen-solver is not guaranteed to output the particular linear combinations that you have in mind.

Comment: Related to this, your Python code should also yield another state with the same energy that [looks like the antisymmetric combination of these functions.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+sin%281*pi*x%29*sin%283*pi*y%29+-+sin%283*pi*x%29*sin%28pi*y%29%2C+x%3D0+to+1%2C+y%3D0+to+1)